# How to write pl/sql source in get restful service handler in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

[image: select descp, id from table1]

Above one is working perfectly in oracle apex. But I want to execute different query based on the id.

[image]

Please suggest me the correct way. I think the screenshots are enough to present my requirements. If need any information please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with pl/sql as source type, the output needs to be generated by the pl/sql procedure (using htp or apex_json). with any "Query" source type, ORDS converts the resultset to json automatically.
However, looking at your example, I doubt you want pl/sql. It can be done with sql and that will be a lot easier to implement.
Here is an example of the source of GET handler on the EMP sample table. For KING (id 7839) another output is generated:

```
select 'The Boss' as nickname, ename from emp where empno = :id AND ename = 'KING'
union
select 'Regular employee' as nickname, ename from emp where empno = :id AND ename != 'KING'
```

If you need pl/sql then here is a simple example:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  
  OPEN l_cursor FOR
    SELECT e.empno AS "empno",
           e.ename AS "employee_name",
           e.job AS "job",
           e.mgr AS "mgr",
           TO_CHAR(e.hiredate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "hiredate",
           e.sal AS "sal",
           e.comm  AS "comm",
           e.deptno AS "deptno"
    FROM   emp e;

  APEX_JSON.open_object;
  APEX_JSON.write('employees', l_cursor);
  APEX_JSON.close_object;
END;
```

Make sure to set the handler "Pagination Size" attribute to an integer value.

There should be plenty of more complex examples available in the web on this. Check the oracle-base site, Jon Dixons' blog and of course Jeff Smith.

Comment: Yes I need pl/sql. Here just I have shown the interface to demonstrate my issue. Actually from client side they send a passcode with the url. Based on the passcode I send them different set of result. The passcode is not a column of the table, it is a external value.

Comment: Thanks it works. Please add a case or if else statement to execute different query based on different id